# React Component doesn't render but there are no error messages

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I've been playing around with a react-google-maps package (https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps) .The component is successfully connecting to maps API as I'm getting various console warnings relating to the key, but nothing is rendering - and there are no error messages. Am I missing something obvious?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {GoogleMap, Loader, Marker} from "react-google-maps";
import { default as ScriptjsLoader } from "react-google-maps/lib/async/ScriptjsLoader";

export default class MapComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      markers: [{
        position: {
          lat: 25.0112183,
          lng: 121.52067570000001,
        },
        key: `Taiwan`,
        defaultAnimation: 2,
      }]
    }
}

 /*
  * This is called when you click on the map.
  * Go and try click now.
  */
 handleMapClick(event) {
   let { markers } = this.state;
   markers = update(markers, {
     $push: [
       {
         position: event.latLng,
         defaultAnimation: 2,
         key: Date.now()
       },
     ],
   });
   this.setState({ markers });

   if (markers.length === 3) {
     this.props.toast(
       `Right click on the marker to remove it`,
       `Also check the code!`
     );
   }
 }

 handleMarkerRightclick(index, event) {
   /*
    * All you modify is data, and the view is driven by data.
    * This is so called data-driven-development. (And yes, it's now in
    * web front end and even with google maps API.)
    */
   let { markers } = this.state;
   markers = update(markers, {
     $splice: [
       [index, 1],
     ],
   });
   this.setState({ markers });
 }

 renderNewBehavior() {
   return (
     <ScriptjsLoader
       hostname={"maps.googleapis.com"}
       pathname={"/maps/api/js"}
       query={{libraries: `geometry,drawing,places` }}
       loadingElement={
         <div {...this.props} style={{ height: `100%` }}>
        LOADING
         </div>
       }
       containerElement={
         <div {...this.props} style={{ height: `100%` }} />
       }
       googleMapElement={
         <GoogleMap
           ref={googleMap => {
             if (!googleMap) {
               return;
             }
             console.log(googleMap);
             console.log(`Zoom: ${ googleMap.getZoom() }`);
             console.log(`Center: ${ googleMap.getCenter() }`);
           }}
           defaultZoom={3}
           defaultCenter={{ lat: -25.363882, lng: 131.044922 }}
           onClick={this.handleMapClick}
         >
           {this.state.markers.map((marker, index) => {
             return (
               <Marker
                 {...marker}
                 onRightclick={this.handleMarkerRightclick.bind(this, index)}
               />
             );
           })}
         </GoogleMap>
       }
     />
   );
 }

 render() {
return this.renderNewBehavior()
 }

}
export default MapComponent
```

Comment: NB It seems likely that this can be fixed using one of the solutions outlined here https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/186

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by setting the containing Div Element to 'style={{ height: '500px' }'.I'm not sure why this worked but it did!